# Zoom in/out on multiple images in android

Tags: android

I am developing an application in which i have an image of map which contains predefined overlay item.now i want that on zoom in zoom out or on drag both, image map and overlay item should be affected by same manner i.e overlay item also should get zoom in/out with image map.My overlay item is a android view.

Answer (score 0):

load your mapview (by address) in webcview like this and provide zooming functionality to webview

```
your_webview_id.loadUrl("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="+your_location_address+"&zoom=14&size=640x640&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C11211%7C11206%7C11222&sensor=true");
```